# How to work around ubuntu php version for composer update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to update my symfony project using composer. I'm running into a strange issue I'm not really sure how to handle. My php version is high enough to update but its formatted in such a way composer wont let me update. Here's my error message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



Problem 1
    - symfony/symfony v3.0.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/symfony v3.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].
```

As you can see, my php version is indeed high enough to update, however, composer says no. How to I force it to update anyway?

Comment: WOW that is a weird error! Since your PHP is 5.6 (that is, PHP > 5.5) it should be okay

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `vendor/` directory? It worked for me several times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to I force it to update anyway?

With the *--ignore-platform-reqs* option composer ignore all the *php*, *ext-**, *lib-** requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The option is available also for `create-project`, `remove` and `require`.

The documentation can be read [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md).